# Flutter - create Blob from base64

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter

I need to convert the base64 string to Blob in order to store in database. Is it possible in flutter. Whatever i tried so far are only converting to base64 by encoding and converting back to image by decoding the base64. I have no idea how to convert a base64 into blob in flutter. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `I need to convert the base64 string to Blob in order to store in database. `. No. You can just put the base64 string as blob in your database. You can put anything as a blob.

Comment: Any idea how to do that in flutter? In javascript i used blob() to convert base64 to blob format. But no idea how to do that in flutter.                                                                                     
                var imageobj = null;
                  fetch(base64)
                    .then((res) => res.blob())
                    .then((blob) => {
                      console.log("here is your binary: ", blob);
                      imageobj = blob;
                    });

Comment: Sorry, i do not use Flutter. Must be a pretty standard operation i think.