# How to convert an Image or base64 to Blob in Dart

Tags: image, flutter, dart, blob, image-conversion

I am getting Image in response from restful API. Then i am converting it to base64 and displaying in a widget. now i want to hit the same image in the another API but this time I've to convert the image or base64 to Blob. Please do let me if you can help me on this.
Thank you.

Comment: You said you got a blob and converted it to base64 and now you don't know how to convert it back. Is that correct? Can you maybe show us some code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632831/flutter-create-blob-from-base64